# EPPlus - Mark cell as date data type without providing format

Tags: excel, epplus

I have website application, where I generate excel file (server side).

```
// Get data to collection
var dates = _dbContext.dates.Select(x => new { x.FirstColumn, Date = Convert.ToDateTime(x.Date) }).ToList();

// Load collection into excel
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(dates, true, TableStyles.Medium6);
```

[image]

Now date column shows integer numbers (probably OADate (OLE Automation Date)).

The question is, can I somehow mark the date column as datetime without providing a specific format ? Just to switch category to date. The reason is that I do not know the language (and specific computer format settings) of the user and I want excel to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller you can capture the current users language settings from the Request Object, like so:

```
string language= Request.UserLanguages.FirstOrDefault() ?? "en-US";
```

If, for whatever reason, the collection is empty, you set a fallback language, here it is US English.
You then pass this string to your Excel function, and the first things you do in that function, is to create a new CultureInfo object with the users language and change it in the current thread:

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = new CultureInfo(language, false);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
```

You can now style the cells of your choice, with the correct format by using the `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` type:

```
// Load collection into excel AND FORMAT THE CELLS
workSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(dates, true, TableStyles.Medium6).Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
```